# Is there a way to see an event when the system caret is visible or not?

Tags: caret

Is there an event that fires when the system caret (text cursor) appears and disappears system wide regardless of application or window?

Assume that the applicatiosn are all well behaved Windows apps.  Apps like Firefox that manage the text cursor themselves are not an issue for me.

I need to know when the system caret is visible so I can start an accessibility support process as well as when it it no visible so I can "sleep" the support aplication.

I am writing my project in C# but C++ samples would be fine.

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, [`EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE` and `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are fired for the caret (`OBJID_CARET`).